# How can I access ResourceDictionary in wpf from C# code?

Tags: c#, wpf, resources

I have a `DataTemplate` defined in a xaml file that I want to access via C# code.
Can anyone please tell me how can I access it?
I added a new `ResourceDictionary` file and its name is **Dictionary1.xaml**. 
  I have a data template such as:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <DataTemplate x:Key="mytemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="Name:" Background="Blue"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

not I have a `ListBox` called listBox1 and I want to assign it to it's `Itemtemplate` property
but I'm not getting how can i do it?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Where exactly are you defining it?

If you define it in the ResourceDictionary of your object, then

```
Application.Current.Resources[typeof(yourDataTemplateTargetType)]
```

should work. If you are defining it as a member of something else, like say, an ItemsControl, you need to get a handle to the ItemsControl instance and call the ItemTemplate property.

Edit: Ok, I think we're getting somewhere. So you are defining a ResourceDictionary in its own file. Before you can use it in your UI and access it from your code behind, you need to merge that ResourceDictionary into your application. Are you doing this?

If you are, then the next step is to get this resource. Each FrameworkElement has a method called [FindResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findresource.aspx). This method is great because it walks up the ResourceDictionary tree and attempts to locate the resource with the key. So, if you want to access this resource from a UserControl, you can do the following in the code behind:

```
FindResource(typeof(yourDataTemplateTargetType));
```

If this doesn't work for you, please show us exactly how you are declaring this resource dictionary and how it is getting merged into your application's resources.

Comment: I don't understand. This answer doesn't use the key.

Comment: FindResource takes one argument, the key. typeof(yourDataTemplateTargetType) is the key in this example.

Comment: Hi. What if the key isn't a Type, but a string as in OP's example?

Comment: Is it that one should set the DataType attribute on the DataTemplate element, rather than use string keys?

Comment: It can be anything. The type of the argument for FindResource is object.

Comment: why is this upvoted, it does not answer the questionat all

Comment: I couldn't get the `FindResource` method to work in my UserControl's codebehind until I had added the resource in the user control's resources in its XAML.  It makes sense, but you gotta use your own brain, took me ages!

Answer (score 74):

Since `Application.Current` was null in my case, I've ended up using this:

```
    var myResourceDictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
    myResourceDictionary.Source =
        new Uri("/DllName;component/Resources/MyResourceDictionary.xaml",
                UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

and then getting the specified key I needed by using
`myResourceDictionary["KeyName"] as TypeOfItem`

([source](http://akashsoni7.blogspot.co.il/2012/12/wpf-how-to-use-resource-dictionary-in-c.html))

Comment: I personally think this is the best approach, as if you was to define this in a library or anywhere, it would still work, where as the Accepted answer, you have to merge all dictionaries into your application, which may be an overkill, or not viable.

Comment: `";component/Styles/Icons.xaml"` is also enough if the dictionary is not in a different assembly.

Comment: So, the point here is that `";component/"` points to the root of your project's file structure (in your current assembly in this example).

Comment: I agree, this is by far the best answer as it will always work. I was initially wondering if you'd have to set the build property of your resource dictionary to "Resources" but you don't, just use the actual path of your resource dict relative to your project, for instance mine ended up being:

 `new Uri("/DllName;component/App/Views/aGeneralResources/StatusBadges.xaml, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);`.

Answer (score 7):

If you for example have a template for Button in your resource dictionary in the App.xaml file you can access it using the following code:

```
Application.Current.Resources[typeof(Button)]
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're getting the resources within the same project, try this:

```
yourControl.Style = FindResource("YourResourceKey") as Style;
```

Otherwise, try this:

```
ResourceDictionary res = (ResourceDictionary)Application.LoadComponent(new Uri("/ProjectName;component/FolderName/ResourceDictionaryName.xaml", UriKind.Relative)); 
yourControl.Style = (Style)res["YourResourceKey"];
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have merged resource dictionary using code like below

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="DefaultStyle.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
</Window>
```

Then, instead of Application.Current.Resources["ResourceKey"] you need to specify Control name (in this case MainWindow) also like below

```
var style = Application.Current.MainWindow.Resources["ResourceKey"];
// OR
var style = Application.Current.MainWindow.TryFindResource("ResourceKey");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access a resource dictionary you added to your project as follows:

```
var rd = new ResourceDictionary();
rd.Source = new Uri("ms-appx:///Dictionary1.xaml");
```

Then you can access a resource stored in the resource dictionary like so:

```
someObject.Property = rd["mytemplate"];
```

**NOTE:**
You will have to modify the URI to the resource dictionary according to the location you created it relative to the project's base directory.

Comment: This is not a WPF solution, the `ms-appx` syntax only works in UWP

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/how-to-use-a-resourcedictionary-to-manage-localizable-string-resources

- create a ressource dictionary "ColorResources.xaml"
- add to it:
   Blue
- edit your app.xml and add:
- use the color from your code

  var color = (System.Windows.Media.Color)Application.Current.FindResource("ButtonColor1");

and voilà

ps : admin can you fix the code? it does not show up, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Any of the above approaches work getting the resource based on the location, if you are following MVVMm I would recommend doing it this way:

1. create a Service like ProvideDataTemplateService, (to create a service usual inherit from Behavior )
2. Use Container of Your choice to inject this service where you would like to have aces to DataTemple.

Answer (score 0):

For the life of me, although I was able to load my resource dictionary via XAML, I wasn't able to load it via "code behind" (in C#).

So I resorted to have a view loading it: (MyView.xaml)

```
  <UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/My.Proj;component/My/Path/myResourceDictionary.xaml" />
      </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </UserControl.Resources>
```

Then access it in my UT by instanciating that view and accessing it:

`new MyView().Resources.MergedDictionaries[0]`

Hacky, but works.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add another answer here in case you don't have a view or `Application.Current` is null.  I realize this is probably uncommon but in my case I have an addin to a parent application and `Application.Current` is null; I also want to pass one of my resources to the parent as an `ImageSource` so I don't have a XAML view created to get resources from directly.

You can also make the dictionary into a code behind creatable object.  Just set the `x:Class` attribute in the XAML and then create a `.xaml.cs` file in the code behind.  Your updated XAML, lets call the code file `MyDictionary.xaml`, would then look something like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                    x:Class="Some.Namespace.MyDictionary"
                    mc:Ignorable="d">
    ...Resources...
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And the code behind (`MyDictionary.xaml.cs`) would look something like this:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace Some.Namespace
{
    public partial class MyDictionary : ResourceDictionary
    {
        public MyDictionary()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to call `InitializeComponent()` as that's what loads the resources. **Actually not sorry, see edit below**

After you do this you can simply construct an instance of the class anywhere in code and reference the resources by key like this:

```
var dictionary = new MyDictionary();
var resource = dictionary["whateverKey"] as WhateverResourceType;
```

Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92100/is-it-possible-to-set-code-behind-a-resource-dictionary-in-wpf-for-event-handlin) for leading to the idea.

**EDIT**

Just ran into one potential issue with this.  I got a 'Cannot re-initialize ResourceDictionary instance' exception with this setup on some of my controls.  On further research this could be related to calling `InitializeComponent` in the constructor.  Instead I removed the constructor from the code behind and added a static method to get an initialized instance as follows:

```
public static MyDictionary ConstructInitializedInstance()
{
    var dictionary = new MyDictionary();
    dictionary.InitializeComponent();
    return dictionary;
}
```

You could also just create and initialize in your code behind.