# Passing BitmapImage as Tag to DataTemplate

Tags: wpf

I'm a bit unexperienced in WPF and trying to get a simple Template in WPF for a button with an Image icon in addition to text to work.

Style code:

```
<Style x:Key="DatabaseButtonWithImageTag" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource DatabaseButton}">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Image Grid.Column="0" Width="100" Source="{TemplateBinding Tag}" />
                    <ContentControl Grid.Column="1" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" /> 
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

View code:

```
       <Image Source="{StaticResource image_new_patient}"/>
    <Button Style="{StaticResource DatabaseButtonWithImageTag}" Tag="{StaticResource image_new_patient}" Width="150" Height="100">
        Test!
    </Button>
```

The image outside the button is displayed, so is "Test!", but there is no image inside the button.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change WPF button background image programatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15819796/change-wpf-button-background-image-programatically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TemplateBinding does not work within a DataTemplate.

You can use this workaroud:

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="image_new_patient" UriSource="bsp.jpg" />
    <local:ImageConverter x:Key="imageConverter" />
    <Style x:Key="DatabaseButtonWithImageTag" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Image Grid.Column="0" Width="100" Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}, Path=Tag}"  />

                        <ContentControl Grid.Column="1" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <Image Source="{StaticResource image_new_patient}" Width="50"/>
    <Button Style="{StaticResource DatabaseButtonWithImageTag}" Tag="{StaticResource image_new_patient}" Width="150" Height="100">
        Test!
    </Button>

</StackPanel>
```