# Setting Control Template Dynamically in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, templates

```
 <s:FastLineRenderableSeries.PointMarker>

  <s:SpritePointMarker PointMarkerTemplate="{StaticResource AnyWpfControlTemplateCanGoHere}"/>
```

Based on the user selection from many options, I need to set this template at runtime. The template is already been defined in generic dictionary which is like this

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="RightTriangleAnnotations">
   <Polygon Points="0 0, 20 20,0 20" x:Name="poly" Fill="Green" Stroke="Red"></Polygon>
```

My code is something like this

```
  var pointMarker = new SpritePointMarker();
  pointMarker.Template = **Here the template should go**
  renderSeries.PointMarker = pointMarker;
```

Any idea how could I set the template at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicaly, that depends on where your resources are defined. You just need to get the template from the dictionary.
For example if your dictionary is defined for an application:

```
Application.Current.Resources["RightTriangleAnnotations"] as ControlTemplate
```

Or you can use any visual object such as **SpritePointMarker::Resources** if dictionary is directly attached to it in XAML. Please refer to this question for detailed solution: [How can I access ResourceDictionary in wpf from C# code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618648/how-can-i-access-resourcedictionary-in-wpf-from-c-sharp-code)

OR if you haven't specified your dictionary in any XAML file you have to load dictionary first and then assign it to a visual object to be able to get the desired resource by key. Check this question for detailed info: [Access ResourceDictionary items programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032294/access-resourcedictionary-items-programmatically)