# Create an element from template programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'd like to move an element from one grid into another and have a problem to assign programmatically a template to the new instance. Further, details of my attempt.

For this purpose, I create an instance of the class together with its visual appearance from the template.

Inside the Window tag I declare the namespace:

```
xlmns:my="clr-namespace:myNameSpace"
```

I have a template in resources:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="templateX">
    <StackPanel>
        <Image Source="pic.png" Width="50" Height="50"/>
    </StackPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

and place the element into the grid.

```
<Grid Grid.Row="2">
    <StackPanel>
        <my:someClass Template="{StaticResource templateX}" MouseMove="_event">
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Now, I drag the element, the event "_event" fires. If I push a standard element (e.g. Rectangle) through this, I do the following at the end of the drag-n-drop chain of events:

```
Rectangle new_instance = new Rectangle();
// place for rectangle's form and color
NewPlace.Children.Add(new_instance);
// place for positioning the rectangle in NewPlace canvas
```

How, can I do the last part with the element of someClass? If I do

```
someClass new_instance = new someClass();
NewPlace.Children.Add(new_instance);
```

the template "templateX" isn't assigned to it.

Comment: Is your *actual* question how to retrieve a particular resource from code-behind, as discussed e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618648/how-can-i-access-resourcedictionary-in-wpf-from-c-sharp-code), or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117886/accessing-a-resource-via-codebehind-in-wpf)?

Comment: If a get the template like this: ContentTemplate CT = (ContentTemplate).this.FindName("templateX")    I can't use it in NewPlace.Children.Add()

Comment: Do you mean `ControlTemplate`? You should not directly add a control template to the `Children` list. Instead, can you assign the control template to `new_instance.Template` before adding `new_instance`? If `someClass` is a control, that should be possible (and if it isn't, a control template is not a suitable way, anyway).

Comment: It worked out, thanks! More precisely, the lines`someClass new_instance = someClass(); ControlTemplate template = (ControlTemplate)this.FindResource("templateX"); new_instance.Template=template;`. Would you like to post your answer to be accepted?

Comment: Done, posted an answer with a somewhat more structured explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue in this case seems to be that you want to combine two things:

- an instance of your custom class (`new_instance`)
- a control template available as a XAML resource

You already know how to create the instance of your class and how to add it to the `Children` list.

How to retrieve the control template (or for that matter, any other object) from a XAML resource has been discussed in other SO questions, e.g.:

- [How can I access ResourceDictionary in wpf from C# code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618648/how-can-i-access-resourcedictionary-in-wpf-from-c-sharp-code)
- [Accessing a resource via codebehind in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117886/accessing-a-resource-via-codebehind-in-wpf)

This leads to:

```
ControlTemplate template = (ControlTemplate)this.FindResource("templateX");
```

Now, the crucial point is that you do *not* want to add the control template itself to the `Children` list. The control template is just a set of instructions how to create a UI tree for your control and bind its properties to those of your control, where appropriate.

Instead, you want to configure `new_instance` to use the control template you retrieved from the resource. You can do that by assigning the control template to the [`Template` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.template%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of `new_instance`:

```
new_instance.Template = template;
```

Once `new_instance` is added to `Children`, it will be displayed and it will use your custom control template.