# changing xamarin.forms colors at runtime

Tags: c#, xamarin, themes, xamarin.forms

i am making an app using xamarin.forms and i have set up a color scheme that i want to be able to change within the settings to either a dark style or a light style right now it all works except i have to restart the app everytime after i select a different color scheme.

here is where i am trying to change it at runtime

```
   private void DarkThemeClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        database.DropTable(new StyleModel());
        database.CreateTable(new StyleModel());
        database.SaveItem(new StyleModel() { ThemeNum = 1 });
        App.ActiveStyle = new DarkStyle();
    }

    private void LightThemeClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        database.DropTable(new StyleModel());
        database.CreateTable(new StyleModel());
        database.SaveItem(new StyleModel() { ThemeNum = 0 });
        App.ActiveStyle = new LightStyle();
    }
```

here is an example of an item that im using that i want to change the colors on

```
    using System;
using TestXamForms.Style;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace TestXamForms.Helpers
{
class EntryValueCell : StackLayout
{

    public EntryValueCell(string key,int FieldIdx, string value = "",  bool isNumber = false)
    {
        Entry entry;
        Label label = new Label()
        {
            TextColor = App.ActiveStyle.LabelTextColor,
            Text = key,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End
        };
        if (isNumber)
        {
            entry = new Entry()
            {
                ClassId = FieldIdx.ToString(),
                TextColor = App.ActiveStyle.LabelTextColor,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                Keyboard = Keyboard.Numeric,
                Text = value, 


            };
        }
        else
        {
            entry = new Entry()
            {
                ClassId = FieldIdx.ToString(),
                TextColor = App.ActiveStyle.LabelTextColor,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                Keyboard = Keyboard.Text,
                Text = value
            };
        }

        BackgroundColor = App.ActiveStyle.StackLayoutBackground;
        Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal;
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
        Children.Add(label);
        Children.Add(entry);
    }
}
}
```

here is an example of one of the color schemes

```
    using Xamarin.Forms;

   namespace TestXamForms.Style
 {
     public  class LightStyle : StyleBase
    {
       public LightStyle()
        {
        LabelTextColor = Color.Black;
        ButtonColor = Color.FromHex("337ab7");
        StackLayoutBackground = Color.FromHex("eff0f1");
        InputBackgroundColor = Color.White;
        PlaceHolderColor = Color.Gray;
        TableColor = Color.FromHex("e6e6e6");
        StacklayoutBorderColor = Color.Black;
       }
      }
     }
```

here is styleBase that the file above is inheriting

```
using TestXamForms.Models;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace TestXamForms.Style
{
public class StyleBase : ModelBase
{
    public enum ThemeNum : int
    {
        Light = 0, Dark = 1
    }
    public Color LabelTextColor { get; set; }
    public Color ButtonColor { get; set; }
    public Color StackLayoutBackground { get; set; }
    public Color InputBackgroundColor { get; set; }
    public Color PlaceHolderColor { get; set; }

    public Color StacklayoutBorderColor { get; set; }

    public Color TableColor { get; set; }

    public int ThemeNums { get; set; }

}
}
```

here is the part of App.cs file that loads the color scheme when the app starts

```
    static StyleBase activeStyle { get; set; }


    public static StyleBase ActiveStyle
    {
        get
        {
            if (activeStyle == null)
            {
                StyleModel styleBase = database.GetItems(new     StyleModel()).First();
                if (styleBase == null)
                {
                    database.SaveItem(new StyleModel() { ThemeNum = 0 }); //sets the default color scheme to light style 
                    styleBase = database.GetItems(new StyleModel()).First();
                }
                int themeNum = styleBase.ThemeNum;
                switch (themeNum)
                {
                    case (int)StyleBase.ThemeNum.Dark:
                        activeStyle = new DarkStyle();
                        break;
                    case (int)StyleBase.ThemeNum.Light:
                        activeStyle = new LightStyle();
                        break;
                }
            }
            return activeStyle;
        }
        set { } }
```

Comment: do you want to change the theme the moment you have the click event?

Comment: ya i would like to have it change at that moment and then save that selection the next time you open the app ..the second part is working now

Comment: Once a view is already rendered it will not update unless you are binding to a property. In other words you need to re-render everything from beginning.

Comment: ok that would make sense thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this [blog post](https://blog.xamarin.com/easy-app-theming-with-xamarin-forms-styles/). Particularly the bit about `DynamicResources` and `Styles`.

```
<Application
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="Your.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Color x:Key="backgroundColor">#33302E</Color>
            <Color x:Key="textColor">White</Color>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Now set your resources

```
<Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes = "Bold" TextColor = "{DynamicResource textColor}" LineBreakMode="NoWrap"/>
<Label Text="{Binding Text}" FontSize="Small" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" TextColor = "{DynamicResource textColor}"/>
```

Now in code you can change your resource on the fly

```
App.Current.Resources ["backgroundColor"] = Color.White;
App.Current.Resources ["textColor"] = Color.Black;
```

If you're using 2.3 you could also try the [built in themes](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/themes/)

Comment: Thanks for this. I can now  change the forms colors at runtime.

Comment: See this for merged dictionaries: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62850549/896631

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is that everything is already rendered and you have not bound to any property which will re render the changes you made in the code to the UI. You can take the MVVM approach and create properties and bind to them and notify when they are changed in the UI thread.

If you are interested only in dark and light themes then you can use the in built [Light Theme](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/themes/light/) and [Dark Theme](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/themes/dark/). You can also create [Custom Themes](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/themes/custom/).

> A theme is added to a Xamarin.Forms application by including the
>   Xamarin.Forms.Theme.Base Nuget package, plus an additional package
>   that defines a specific theme (eg. Xamarin.Forms.Theme.Light) or else
>   a local theme can be defined for the application.

In addition to automatically styling the common controls the Light and Dark themes currently support the following classes that can be applied by setting the StyleClass on these controls:

- BoxView - 
  HorizontalRule,
  Circle,
  Rounded
- Image -
  Circle, 
  Rounded,
  Thumbnail
- Button - 
  Default,
  Primary,
  Success,
  Info,
  Warning,
  Danger,
  Link,
  Small,
  Large
- Label -
  Header, 
  Subheader,
  Body,
  Link,
  Inverse

To add a theme to your application, do the following :

1. Add the Nuget packages to your project.
2. Add theme to Resource Dictionary in App.xaml
3. Use the Style class to apply predefined style classes in the theme.

   ```
   <Button Text="Button Class Default" StyleClass="Default" />
   <Button Text="Button Class Primary" StyleClass="Primary" />
   <Button Text="Button Class Success" StyleClass="Success" />
   ```

Read more about themes [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/themes/).