# How to set/change XML values at runtime?

Tags: xml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

in my application I want to implement multiple themes (Light and Dark), this, I created 2 `ResourceDictionary` XAML files with the exact same key names and I merge them to **App.xaml** depending on the on going required theme.

The problem comes with Android/IOS specific properties existsing in XML (in Android for example) where they don't obey the **App.xaml** file. So I end up with my application in dark theme for example with `<TimePicker/>` element for example with colors of the default light theme.

So I would like to be able to change Android **XML** colors file **colors.xml** and **styles.xml** parameters an its equivalent in IOS depending on my needs, changing the color accent for example and so on.

Thanks in advance ^^.

**=============== Update 1 ===============**

Maybe if I can make the **XML** file get its value from a dynamic resource, app property or a code ? I can make the change theme event set the resource or the app property or even make a code that dynamically decides which values to be put.

Any help ?

**=============== Update 2 ===============**

Maybe we can just override the **colors.xml** and **styles.xml** files with another way? Or maybe create 2 **color.xml** and **styles.xml** files and load them according to a code ?!

Comment: I think you are in the correct track. just switch xml file dynamically in code level.
add some code you have done until this point. then we can help you.

Comment: Well, can you help me out with that ? How to switch xml files dynamically ?

Comment: You could refer to the link below: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48465053/can-i-programmatically-change-styles-xml-in-xamarin-forms

Comment: It doesn't tell me how to do it, instead, they are talking about XAML not XML, there is a comment talking about XML but doesn't tell me how to switch XML styles...

Comment: The link suggest to set the style in style.xml. And you could try to reset the style at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

When a theme is selected at runtime, the application should:

1. Remove the current theme from the application. This is achieved by clearing the MergedDictionaries property of the application-level ResourceDictionary.
2. Load the selected theme. This is achieved by adding an instance of the selected theme to the MergedDictionaries property of the application-level ResourceDictionary.

Any VisualElement objects that set properties with the DynamicResource markup extension will then apply the new theme values. This occurs because the DynamicResource markup extension maintains a link to dictionary keys. Therefore, when the values associated with keys are replaced, the changes are applied to the VisualElement objects.

In the sample application, a theme is selected via a modal page that contains a Picker. The following code shows the OnPickerSelectionChanged method, which is executed when the selected theme changes:

```
void OnPickerSelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Picker picker = sender as Picker;
    Theme theme = (Theme)picker.SelectedItem;

ICollection<ResourceDictionary> mergedDictionaries = Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries;
if (mergedDictionaries != null)
{
    mergedDictionaries.Clear();

    switch (theme)
    {
        case Theme.Dark:
            mergedDictionaries.Add(new DarkTheme());
            break;
        case Theme.Light:
        default:
            mergedDictionaries.Add(new LightTheme());
            break;
    }
}
}
```

source -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/theming/theming#load-a-theme-at-runtime

and this post will help you
https://www.sharpnado.com/dark-light-mode/

for more -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/material-theme

Comment: Nooo, I already did that, my issue is with the xml. I did exactly like what you posted but as I said in the question, I need to change the xml **styles.xml** file in order to make the splash screen, statues bar and other accents in the app to follow the new color theme.