# Need help handling events of a DataTemplate in the Application.xaml file

Tags: wpf, event-handling, datatemplate, event-triggers

I have in my application a data template that has a few buttons.
I want those buttons' even handler to be fired in the current page (I am using this template in many pages) rather than in the Application.xaml.vb/cs file, since I want different actions on each page.

I hope I am clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use commanding to achieve this. Have the `Button`s in the `DataTemplate` execute specific `Command`s:

```
<Button Command="{x:Static MyCommands.SomeCommand}"/>
```

Then have each view that uses that `DataTemplate` handle the `Command`:

```
<UserControl>
    <UserCommand.CommandBindings>
         <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static MyCommands.SomeCommand}"
                         Executed="_someHandler"/>
    </UserCommand.CommandBindings>
</UserControl>
```

**EDIT after comments:** Once you have created a code-behind for your `ResourceDictionary` as per [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92100/is-it-possible-to-set-code-behind-a-resource-dictionary-in-wpf-for-event-handli), you can simply connect events in the usual fashion:

In `MyResources.xaml`:

```
<ListBox x:Key="myListBoxResource" ItemSelected="_listBox_ItemSelected"/>
```

Then in `MyResources.xaml.cs`:

```
private void _listBox_ItemSelected(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Then how would you set some of the events in the code behind?
And what if I use ResourceDictionary (that doesn't have a code behind file) and I want to refer to a handler in the ResourceDictionary page itself.

Comment: You can easily have a code-behind file for a ResourceDictionary. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92100/is-it-possible-to-set-code-behind-a-resource-dictionary-in-wpf-for-event-handli

Comment: 1) please edit the 2nd snippet regarding how to address the event to a local handler.
2) what's MyCommands, a declaration?

Comment: 1) OK, edited. 2) You'll need to read up on commanding and routed commands in particular.

Comment: I don't want to fire the ItemSelected event, I want to fire the event in the DataTemplate's button, since I have many button's in the template (i.e. remove, edit, move up, move down and more plenty of buttons).

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you use events and not commands, then in your `Click` event handler just write

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var dataItem = (FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext;
    // process dataItem
}
```