# Control's event to external static class method

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, events, xaml

I want to create a static class where I will have some common methods which I will using in events. So for example I did a following class:

```
public static class CommonMethodsProvider {

    public static void CommonEventHandler( object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e ) {
        // ...
    }

}
```

And in xaml code I tried to do it like that:

```
<... Handler="CommonMethodsProvider.CommonEventHandler" ... />
```

Is there any way to use it in WPF controls?

I receive error:

> PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="CommonMethodsProvider.CommonEventHandler" is not valid. 'CommonMethodsProvider.CommonEventHandler' is not a valid event handler method name. Only instance methods on the generated or code-behind class are valid.

So isn't there any opportunity to do it?

Comment: pls take a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761114/call-events-or-methods-located-in-a-class-from-xaml

Comment: Its more about behaviors, but I need as simple as it is possible solution to make this event running method from external Class.

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor, in the code behind, after `InitializeComponent();`
add lines such as

```
MyControl.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += CommonMethodsProvider.CommonEventHandler;
```