# Close, minimize and maximize events do not work in a custom WPF form template

Tags: c#, wpf, controltemplate, resourcedictionary

I'm designing a custom form in a WPF ResourceDictionary using a controltemplate so I can easily use the window later on. I'm designing it with Expression Blend and I'm stuck on getting the close, maximize and minimize buttons to work.

At first I wasn't able to access any of the events, however [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92100/is-it-possible-to-set-code-behind-a-resource-dictionary-in-wpf-for-event-handling) stackoverflow question helped me with binding a class to the resourcedictionary. When I try to access the click event for the close, min and max buttons, I get in the code editor and the btn_Close eventhandler shows up.

When I try to compile it gives me the error "application.Resources doesn't contain a defition for close (...)" (Resources is the name of the class)
(when I type "this." intellisense gives me many commands but not .Close)

I'm pretty sure all of the namespaces in both the class and XAML are right, how do I get this working properly? Or do I need to code this seperately for each form that uses this template?

Comment: Why dont you have a look at [This][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792275/how-to-create-custom-window-chrome-in-wpf

Answer (score 0):

In the strange situation you've arranged, `this` in the code-behind does not refer to a `Window` but to the `ResourceDictionary`.  Nevertheless, the event when it occurs will be generated by a window so instead of using `this` you need to cast the `sender` parameter to a `Window` and `Close` that instead.