# ResourceDictionary Adding x:Class

Tags: wpf, resourcedictionary, code-behind

In a first attempt to create a DataTemplate I added the class from MainWindow to access eventhandlers. Now this may be incorrect for a number of reasons (and produces some interesting error messages) however I'd like to understand why a ResourceDictionary is unable to reference a partial class such as MainWindow ?

xaml as follows (note that this fails without any events implemented)

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
>
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
</Window>
```

Resource dic.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
x:Class="MainWindow"
>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Any thoughts much appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have a resource dictionary backed up by something like a `MainWindow` because `MainWindow` does not inherit from `ResourceDictionary` class.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92100/is-it-possible-to-set-code-behind-a-resource-dictionary-in-wpf-for-event-handling) article for better understanding of the use of code behind resource dictionaries ...

I hope this answers your question.