# ResourceDictionary From External Assembly [read object from UnmanagedMemoryStream]

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, reflection

I have an `UnmanagedMemoryStream` in below code, How can I get the object from deserilizing it. I was trying to get a `Resource` (rd.xaml) from an `Assembly` :

```
string address = @"WpfControlLibrary1.dll";
Assembly skinAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(address);
string name = skinAssembly.GetName().Name +".g";
var manager = new ResourceManager(name, skinAssembly);
ResourceSet rs = manager.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, true, true);

UnmanagedMemoryStream stream = (UnmanagedMemoryStream)rs.GetObject("rd.baml", true);
```

I'm not able to `deserialize` the content of `Stream` into a .net `Object`(which is a `Resource Dictionary` in above case). How can I do this?

**PS:** `BinaryFormatter` is throwing an exception while `Deserialize` operation.

Comment: What exception? In which line?

Comment: {"The input stream is not a valid binary format. The starting contents (in bytes) are: 0C-00-00-00-4D-00-53-00-42-00-41-00-4D-00-4C-00-00 ..."}

Comment: add these lines in my code: BinaryFormatter binForm = new BinaryFormatter();
            Object obj = (Object)binForm.Deserialize(stream);

Comment: Did you serialized the resource dictionary with the same formatter that you use to deserialize? It looks like you are trying to do something strange. `rs.GetObject` already returns an Object according to MSDN. And then you are trying to assign it to a stream? And then deserialize?

Comment: Well, I didn't serialize resource  it was as it is, all I'm doing is trying to get it from another assembly  using reflection. and getObject returns UnmangedMemoryStream... use the ccode...see it yourself it doesn't return any other object.

Comment: [ResourceSet.GetObject(String, bool)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x0247w2(v=vs.110).aspx) returns Object.

Comment: @cassandradied And this case the object is UnmanagedMemoryStream .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is how I've done it, with optimized code:

```
public ResourceDictionary GetResourceDictionary(string assemblyName)
    {
        Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyName);
        Stream stream = asm.GetManifestResourceStream(asm.GetName().Name + ".g.resources");            
        using (ResourceReader reader = new ResourceReader(stream))
        {
            foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in reader)
            {
                var readStream = entry.Value as Stream;
                Baml2006Reader bamlReader = new Baml2006Reader(readStream);
                var loadedObject = System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(bamlReader);
                if (loadedObject is ResourceDictionary)
                {
                    return loadedObject as ResourceDictionary;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

***OUTPUT:***

[image: output]

> ***I wanted to read a `ResourceDictionary` from an External Assembly/Another Project, So that I can iterate it's `Resources` to
>   use.***