# Access a Named ResourceDictionary that has CodeBehind

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, .net-4.0

I have a ResourceDictionary that I have [setup to have codebehind](https://stackoverflow.com/a/98422/16241).

That codebehind also has a combobox drop down list from my database that I need to initialize.  Since this is a "view" level object, I don't want to connect it up to my "model" level objects directly.

So, I need to find a way to get access to this object.  The problem is that this "class" is created by the View's call to `InitializeComponent()`.  So I can't just pass in the stuff I need as params.

I have tried to get the resource and cast it to my "class" but that does not work.  (Invalid cast)

```
ResourceDictionary resource = new ResourceDictionary
{
  Source=new Uri("/MyProject;component/MyClass.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
};

var myClass = resource as MyClass;
myClass.ListOfItems = listOfItems;
```

My last resort is to create static methods and pass the references I need that way.  But that tightly couples these two classes.  So I thought I would see if there is a better way that any one knows...

Answer (score 0):

Have you inherited your class (`MyClass`) from `ResourceDictionary` before you can cast it?

You can also try

```
List<MyClass> listOfItem = new List<MyClass>(ResourceDisctionaryCollection);
```