# How to set a binding source to the codebehind of a ResourceDictionary

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xml

I have a ResourceDictionary that I [added a codebehind](https://stackoverflow.com/a/98422/16241) to.

In the ResourceDictionary I have a combobox.  I want to bind the ItemsSource of that combobox to a List in the codebehind.

How can I set the source of my binding so that it looks in the codebehind?

```
This one uses the code behind --------+
                                      |
                                      V
<ComboBox  PreviewKeyDown="CustomItem_PreviewKeyDown"
           ItemsSource="{Binding AllItems, Source={CodeBehind} />
                     ^                                   ^
                     |                                   |
But this one doesn't | because the source is not correct |
```

In case it matters, this is what the start of my ResourceDictionary looks like:

```
<ResourceDictionary 
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                x:Class="MyProject.MyCodeBehindClass"
                x:Name="ANameThatSeemsUselessHere">
```

Any ideas on how I could get the ItemSource binding to the **ResourceDictionary codebehind**?

Comment: I am wondering if you can't put a DataContext in <ResourceDictionary

Comment: ResourceDictionary does not have a data context (items in them can have them).

Answer (score 0):

I think its something like 
    DataContext ="{Static Resource ANameTheSeemsUsl