# WPF: is there an event triggered on resource change

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, resourcedictionary

is there a way to get notified on value changes of a specific *WPF* resource?

We need to dynamically adapt the content font size in a *WPF* application... For *WPF* controls, we set `Control.FontSize` to a dynamic resource and the font resizes automatically. Unfortunately, we also have an embedded *winforms* control, which font size cannot be set that way. The idea was to subscribe to an event triggered on each resource value-change and to implement a custom refresh of the *winforms* control. Any suggestion?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92100/is-it-possible-to-set-code-behind-a-resource-dictionary-in-wpf-for-event-handlin ?

Comment: Code-behind could help declaring a public event. But when should this event be triggered? Is there an event anywhere in WPF framework, that tells us, that a resource has changed?

Comment: I found the event `FrameworkElement.ResourcesChanged` in the **.Net** source, but it is completely ***internal***. No way to hook some handler to this event... Any suggestion? I think the only remaining way, consists of setting the dynamic resource to a dedicated dependency property (using `Prop={DynamicResource MyResource}` and use the dependency property to trigger a change-event)

Answer (score 7):

So,

after considering all possible ways, I introduced a new behavior that triggers an event on each change of a specific `WPF` resource.

The source can be downloaded or cloned from https://github.com/jeromerg/ResourceChangeEvent.

```cs
public class ResourceChangeNotifierBehavior 
  : System.Windows.Interactivity.Behavior<FrameworkElement>
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ResourceProperty 
            = DependencyProperty.Register("Resource", 
                   typeof(object),
                   typeof(ResourceChangeNotifierBehavior),
                   new PropertyMetadata(default(object), ResourceChangedCallback));

    public event EventHandler ResourceChanged;

    public object Resource
    {
        get { return GetValue(ResourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ResourceProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void ResourceChangedCallback(DependencyObject dependencyObject,
                                                DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var resourceChangeNotifier = dependencyObject as ResourceChangeNotifierBehavior;
        if (resourceChangeNotifier == null)
            return;

        resourceChangeNotifier.OnResourceChanged();
    }

    private void OnResourceChanged()
    {
        EventHandler handler = ResourceChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

So that an event-handler `OnResourceChanged` can be hooked in the `XAML` file as following:

```xml
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <Behaviours:ResourceChangeNotifierBehavior 
                Resource="{DynamicResource MyDynamicResourceKey}"
                ResourceChanged="OnResourceChanged"/>
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

Hope, it helps...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I indeed wanted to get notified if any resource changed. In my case, a `DynamicResource` was used on some `DependencyObject` which was not in the visual tree. Therefore, the property did not automatically update if the resource changed.

Using the internal event found by jeromerg, I have written a small extension method to register to the `ResourceChanged` event:

```
public static void NotifyOnResourcesChanged(this FrameworkElement element, EventHandler onResourcesChanged)
{
    ResourcesChangedEvent.AddMethod.Invoke(element, new object[] { onResourcesChanged });
}
private static readonly EventInfo ResourcesChangedEvent = typeof(FrameworkElement).GetEvent("ResourcesChanged", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

In my event handler, I notified the target properties via `InvalidateProperty` to force an update.