# Binding to ContextMenuOpening in DataTemplate within ResourceDictionary XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a ResourceDictionary that contains a `<DataTemplate>` with a `<TextBox>` in it.  The problem is how to use a binding to connect the `ContextMenuOpening` event of the `TextBox`.  I have tried creating a DependencyProperty through `DependencyProperty.Register` with a name that matches the Binding in the `ContextMenuOpening` event, but at runtime the error is:

`A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'AddContextMenuOpeningHandler' property of type 'TextBox'.  A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.`

ResourceDictionary XAML:

```
<DataTemplate>
   <Grid>
       <TextBox ContextMenuOpening="{Binding ??WHAT GOES HERE?? }"  />
   </Grid>       
</DataTemplate>
```

Is what I'm trying to do even possible because of the XAML being in the ResourceDictionary rather than in the XAML of a UserControl?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? You cannot bind an event to a property...what do you want to do when the context menu opens?

Comment: @mm8 I want to add a handler to customize the menu

Comment: An event handler is defined programmatically in the code-behind of the view.

Comment: @mm8, yes, I know, but this is in a ResourceDictionary.  Perhaps it isn't possible then to wire up a handler in this way.

Comment: It is. Please refer to my answer.

Comment: Can't you customize your ContextMenu directly in xaml like in this [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750420(v=vs.110).aspx)? Just using TextBox.ContextMenu and creating items that you need there. Then just bind to MenuItem's Command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is what I'm trying to do even possible because of the XAML being in the ResourceDictionary rather than in the XAML of a UserControl?

Yes, you could add a code-behind file to a ResourceDictionary as described here:

[Is it possible to set code behind a resource dictionary in WPF for event handling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92100/is-it-possible-to-set-code-behind-a-resource-dictionary-in-wpf-for-event-handlin)

Once you have added the code-behind file you could handle the event as usual:

```
<TextBox ContextMenuOpening="TextBox_ContextMenuOpening"  />
```

---

```
private void TextBox_ContextMenuOpening(object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs e)
{
    //do your thing...
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, and while it is not exactly what I was trying to do it is close enough to get the job done.  My problem now is how to get back to the bound object, but I have discovered that the object in the `OnScalingMenuOpening` callback has a `DataContext` that refers back to the bound object.  I can invoke on that object dynamically since the ResourceDictionary is in a different assembly than the bound object that doesn't know about the type of the object bound.  A bit ugly, but it works!   Thanks for the help.  I will accept and vote up the answer.