# access codebehind method from resource dictionary in WPF

Tags: wpf, telerik, code-behind, telerik-grid, resourcedictionary

I have following grid inside WPF XML file

```
<Grid Grid.RowSpan="2" >
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height = "Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions >

    <telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox TextSearchMode = "Contains" Grid.Column= "0" Grid.Row= "0" Name="cmbStyleNo" Margin= "5"
                                 DisplayMemberPath="SAMPLE_ID"  ItemsSource="{Binding Styles}"
                                 SelectionMode= "Single" AutoCompleteMode= "Suggest" NoResultsContent= "No Matches" SelectionChanged= "val_SelectionChanged" />
</Grid >
```

above **RadAutoCompleteBox** SelectionChanged="val_SelectionChanged" code behind method exist in its code-behind file like follows

```
private void val_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

Then I have requirement populate above same grid in another window using resource dictionary. so I copied that grid to that **ResourceDictionary** like follows

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:samplePrjkt"
                    xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation">

    <ToolBar x:Key="MyToolbar" Height="120">
        <!--Template-->
        <GroupBox Header="Template" Style="{StaticResource ToolbarGroup}" Margin="3">
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,2,0,2">

                      <Grid Grid.RowSpan="2" >
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <telerik:RadAutoCompleteBox TextSearchMode="Contains" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Name="cmbStyleNo" Margin="5" 
                                     DisplayMemberPath="SAMPLE_ID"  ItemsSource="{Binding Styles}" 
                                     SelectionMode="Single" AutoCompleteMode="Suggest" NoResultsContent="No Matches" SelectionChanged="val_SelectionChanged"/>
            </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </GroupBox>
    </ToolBar>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

then once I compile this I'm getting following error

> 'ResourceDictionary' root element requires a x:Class attribute to
>   support event handlers in the XAML file. Either remove the event
>   handler for the SelectionChanged event, or add a x:Class attribute to
>   the root element.

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually add a code-behind file for the `ResourceDictionary` and define the `val_SelectionChanged` event handler in this file.

Please refer to the following link for more information and an example of how to do this:

[Is it possible to set code behind a resource dictionary in WPF for event handling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92100/is-it-possible-to-set-code-behind-a-resource-dictionary-in-wpf-for-event-handlin)

You basically just create a new class and name it "Dictionary1.xaml.cs" where "Dictionary1" is the name of your resource dictionary XAML file and then you set the `x:Class` attribute in the XAML file:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                x:Class="WpfApplication1.Dictionary1"
...
```

Comment: can I give the same code behind file, without create new class file  ?

Comment: No. You should create a new code-behind class and copy the event handler over to this one.

Comment: for this purpose can I use user-control and embed grid inside of it and call that user control inside resource-dictionary ?

Comment: Please ask a new question if you have another issue. Don't ask additional questions in the comments field.

Comment: no I 'm asking whether new approach suitable for this purpose or not , 

objective - populate grid with same dropdowns in a diffrent window .  
approach -  can I use user-control and embed grid inside of it and call that user control inside resource-dictionary ?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you could define the Grid in a UserControl and use this UserControl wherever you want. No reason to add the UC to a ResourceDictionary.