# "cannot resolve symbol" in ResourcesDictionary XAML (to be merged)

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary, graph-sharp, eventsetter

I have one file **GraphView.XAML**. I have split the **Resources** section into two **ResourceDictionary** files (**Vertices.xaml** and **Edges.xaml**) which I merge as follows:

**GraphView.XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="graph_app.GraphView" ... >

<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Design/Vertices.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Design/Edges.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Grid.Resources>
    ...
<\Grid>
```

If not split the code works, but if split I get an error in the **Vertices.xaml**, telling me that the method **ChangeVertexColor_OnClick** cannot be resolved:

**Vertices.XAML**

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:graph_app">

      <Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:VertexControl}">
          <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="ChangeVertexColor_OnClick"/>
                                                        ^^^cannot resolve symbol^^^^
      </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I repeat, if put in one single XAML the code works. Moreover, the **ChangeVertexColor_OnClick** method is implemented in **GrapView.xaml.cs** so it should be recognized, but somehow after the split the **Vertices.xaml** is losing track of the **x:Class** (I suppose it ignores its existence since it's a separated file).

How can I access **ChangeVertexColor_OnClick** from the separated ResourcesDictionary file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing strange is happening here :) - it just shouldn't work, because this is the way it's designed. I can see 2 possible solutions:

1. Add codebehind file for your resource dictionary, and put your `ChangeVertexColor_OnClick` method there [read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92100/is-it-possible-to-set-code-behind-a-resource-dictionary-in-wpf-for-event-handlin)
2. Do not set MouseDoubleClick in style, but directly on `controls:VertexControl` (so kind of, revert your split change)

Comment: Thank you @walkerbox , with the solution #1 I'm now able to execute the method OnClick, but since it uses properties of the Current Window (namespace:graph_app) from which the click is received, I was wondering what's the better way to access them from the new class (namespace:graph_app.Design). Thank you!

Comment: I would rather not set events in styles and not use code behind for resource dictionaries. if you want to write nice code, read about MVVM pattern. It's perfect choice for WPF/UWP. if you are new, MVVM is bigger topic, so as a workaround, you could: 1. Not set event in ResourceDictionary or 2. Write a helper class to store your data.

Comment: I've implemented the helper and now all is working like a charm! Thank you @walkerbox