# Define Style in ResourceDictionary, but EventSetter locally

Tags: wpf, datagrid, styling

I have restyled a DataGrid and it got rather complex so I moved the styles (DataGrid, DataGridCell, DataGridRow,...) to a ResourceDictionary. I gave all of them a x:Key and referenced them e.g. as DataGrid.RowStyle="{StaticResource SuperRowStyle}". Now I want to use an EventSetter on the Row as well, but obviously I can't set it in the ResourceDictionary, but I can't set it in the Window as well, since it gets overridden by the RowStyle property. How can I do this?
BR,
Daniel

Comment: Create a new style in the window BasedOn the one defined in the resource dictionary. Use the EventSetter in this style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer it myself as a good solution is provided in the comments. I create a style in the window where I need the EventSetter and use BasedOn with the needed style.

Comment: Geeez, makes total sense. I've been struggling for a couple of hours on this.

Answer (score 0):

> Now I want to use an `EventSetter` on the Row as well, but obviously I can't set it in the `ResourceDictionary` ..

Yes, you can provided that you add a code-behind file to the `ResourceDictionary`:

[Is it possible to set code behind a resource dictionary in WPF for event handling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92100/is-it-possible-to-set-code-behind-a-resource-dictionary-in-wpf-for-event-handlin)

The handler must be defined in the same class as the `EventSetter`.

Comment: I saw that, but I expected to be able to use the Window class for the EventHandler. That is not working however.

Comment: No. As I mentioned, you *cannot* define the EventSetter in one class and the event handler in another. This won't work. But there should be no reason do to this anyway. You could call any method you want in the event handler.