# How to add back-code to an event of a datatemplate's control that is located in a separate xaml file (with no .cs file related)?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, code-behind

Usually, when I build my UWP applications, I put all my `DataTemplate` styles in a separate "Styles.xaml" file, to which the general `ResourceDictionary` in App.xaml is linked to through merging them.

A standard way that all professional developers use.

This time, however, I need to add a function to a certain event in a xaml control inside a DataTemplate, but I know the way of doing it only when the `DataTemplate` itself is defined inline (i.e. in the `ItemTemplate` property).

How can I, then, add some back-code to this event?

-> *Please note that I already know data-binding an event to a function in a ViewModel and I already use it*... this time I'm talking about adding some back-code that is not related to (i.e. contained in) the 'model' itself.

Thank you for your attention.

Best regards.

Comment: It's impossible to achieve what you want.The XAML file is just a static resource file,you can't write a method in it without a .cs file or bind event from other page.The best way is to use data-binding to bind an event to a function in a ViewModel.

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT   So, I guess, I’ll have to continue with inline DataTemplate definitions, on the same page where them are used.  :(

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add a code-behind file to a XAML `ResourceDictionary` using the same approach as described for WPF applications [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/98422/7252182).