# How to disable WPF Expander Control isPressed/onMouseClick event?

Tags: wpf, expander

I have a WPF application with an Expander Control. I want the Expander Control to expand ONLY based on IsMouseOver event. I was able to enable the IsMouseOver behavior by implementing the corresponding trigger in ControlTemplate.Triggers. But I can't figure out how to disable the IsPressed/OnMouseClick events. Any advice on how to do is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please share your custom `ControlTemplate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could handle the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event for the `ToggleButton` that is called "HeaderSite" in the default template:

```
private void HeaderSite_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) 
    => e.Handled = true;
```

**XAML:**

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="HeaderSite" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="HeaderSite_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" ... />
```

Remember that XAML is a *markup* language and that you should implement this kind of behaviour in a programming language such as C#.

If your template is defined in a `ResourceDictionary`, you should add a [code-behind class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92100/is-it-possible-to-set-code-behind-a-resource-dictionary-in-wpf-for-event-handlin) to it and defined the event handler there.

Comment: Thank you mm8. Your answer makes complete sense. When i enter the code, i get the error: CS1061 'App' does not contain a definition for 'HeaderSite_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown' and no accessible extension method 'HeaderSite_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown' accepting a first argument of type 'App' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). I think this has to do with your second comment. My XAML Expander style definition is in App.xaml. What code do i need to add where to address the error?

Comment: @scorpiotomse: Where did you put the event handler? It the style is defined in `App.xaml`, the code goes in `App.xaml.cs`.