# WPF - Using button in dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a WPF app with a Treeview and a detail page.
The detail page is done via several dictionaries to handle the different layouts.
Now I would like to add to the detail a edit and save button.
I can bind it to the model as the data but then I have a problem how to communicate saves from the model to the viewmodel.

But if I put in the dictionary directly the name of a method that is in the code behind of the view I get an error at runtime.

This is the TreeView in the MasterDetailPage.xaml:

```
        <TreeView
        x:Name="TreeView"
        Grid.Row="1"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PAZHTemplate}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Patients}"
        SelectedItemChanged="select_SelectedItemChanged"
        TreeViewItem.Expanded="ExpandItem" />
```

This is the details element:

```
    <ContentControl
    Grid.Column="2"
    Margin="{StaticResource XSmallLeftTopMargin}"
    Content="{Binding Selected}"
    ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ContentTemplateSelector}" />
```

Here we go with the Selector:

```
   <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="TitoDoc\TPazDictionary.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="TitoDoc\TAppDictionary.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

<templateSelectors:TreeViewDataContentTemplateSelector
    x:Key="ContentTemplateSelector"
    APPTemplate="{StaticResource APPContentTemplate}"
    APRTemplate="{StaticResource APRContentTemplate}"/>
```

And here the TPazDictionary.xaml

```
            <Button
                x:Name="Save"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Content="&#xE74E;"
                Command="{Binding CmdSaveSwitch, Mode=OneWay}"
                ContentTemplate="{StaticResource IconFilterButton}"
                DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                ToolTipService.ToolTip="Save"
                Visibility="{Binding IsVisible}" />
            <Button
                x:Name="LockUnlock"
                Grid.Column="2"
                Command="{Binding CmdEditSwitch, Mode=OneWay}"
                Content="{Binding Icon}"
                ContentTemplate="{StaticResource IconFilterButton}"
                DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                ToolTipService.ToolTip="Edit" />

        </Grid>
        <Grid Margin="0,6,0,0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="40" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="40" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="12" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="12" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock
                Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Padding="2"
                Style="{DynamicResource ContentLabel}"
                Text="Cognome" />
            <TextBox
                Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.Column="0"
                IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly}"
                Text="{Binding Paz.Cognome}" />
            <TextBlock
                Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Style="{DynamicResource ContentLabel}"
                Text="Nome" />
            <TextBlock
                Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Style="{DynamicResource ContentData}"
                Text="{Binding Paz.Nome}" />
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

This is the binding with the model:

```
                Command="{Binding CmdSaveSwitch, Mode=OneWay}"
```

but if I put

```
                Command="Save_Click"
```

I get the error even if in MasterDetailPage.xaml.cs the method is defined:

```
    private void Save_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
```

Answer (score 0):

Only properties of types that implement the ICommand interface can be used to bind commands, not methods.

Comment: Sorry so I'm doing something wrong in the declaration of Save_Click? The binding works fine but the method is in the Model so its not where I want it

Answer (score 0):

Event handlers *must* be defined in the same class as the XAML markup, i.e. you *cannot* define the event handler `Save_Click` in `MasterDetailPage.xaml.cs` if you add `Command="Save_Click"` to `TPazDictionary.xaml` or any other file than `MasterDetailPage.xaml`.

You may add a [code-behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92100/is-it-possible-to-set-code-behind-a-resource-dictionary-in-wpf-for-event-handlin) file to the `TPazDictionary.xaml` resource dictionary and define the event handler in there though.

Comment: ouch! but the code behind the TPazDictionary.xaml will not have complete visibility of properties and methods in the MasterDetailPage.xaml.cs ... as the Dictionary was a trick to split big XAML files I was hoping that the code behind the parent page was able to connect to the correct properties

Comment: @MassimoSavazzi: Well, now you know that's not the case.