# Custom control minimize button

Tags: wpf

I want to create a custom minimize button with some specific style so I can use this button in many WPF windows, is there any way to add a click event to that button so it can minimize any form when the button is clicked .. so I don't have to write in each form

`this.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;`

I want to do the same for Close button

I used Custom Control and I've succeeded in using the style I wanted for the button
but I can't add the Event

This is the code in the custom Control

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2">


    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="100"></Setter>
    </Style>
    
    
</ResourceDictionary>
```

and this is the code in the MainForm
`<control:CustomControl1 ></control:CustomControl1>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `Click` event to your Minimize button in your `CustomControl1.xaml` and the following handler to your `CustomControl1.xaml.cs` file:

```
private void MinimizeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Window ownerWindow = Window.GetWindow(this);
    ownerWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
}
```

When you click this button, whatever Window that owns it, the Window will be minimized.

Answer (score 0):

Add a code-behind file for your resource dictionary as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92100/is-it-possible-to-set-code-behind-a-resource-dictionary-in-wpf-for-event-handlin) and then use an `EventSetter` in your `Style`:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="100"></Setter>
    <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="Button_Click" />
</Style>
```

---

```
public partial class Dictionary1 : ResourceDictionary
{
    public Dictionary1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window window = Window.GetWindow(this);
        window.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
    }
}
```