# WinUI 3 How to make DataTemplate usable in all pages?

Tags: winrt-xaml, winui-3, c++-winrt

WinUI 3 c++/winrt. The DataTemplate is listed at the top of the page:

```xml
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="SomeViewTemplate" x:DataType="local:SomeModel">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind val1}"/>
            <RatingControl MaxRating="{x:Bind val2}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
```

Everything works fine on this page. How can I make this DataTemplate usable on other pages? In what place (file) should it be placed?

Comment: As [Lookup behavior for XAML resource references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/style/xaml-resource-dictionary#lookup-behavior-for-xaml-resource-references) said, *If the requested resource is not found in the immediate resources, the next lookup step is to check the Application.Resources property. **Application.Resources** is the best place to put any app-specific resources that are referenced by multiple pages in your app's navigation structure.* @breadman any update?

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT If I put DataTemplate (as in question) in App.xaml in <Application.Resources> in <ResourceDictionary> I get error "WMC9999 ImplementsIObservableVector: XamlType does not have metadata"
If you put it in other places in this file - it also does not work. That other proposed solution also does not work as it should.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have your `DataTemplate` in a ResourceDictionary "DataTemplates.xaml". Note that you need to use `Binding` instead of `x:Bind`.

```xml
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:DataTemplateExample">

     <DataTemplate x:Key="SomeViewTemplate">
         <StackPanel>
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding val1}"/>
             <RatingControl MaxRating="{Binding val2}" />
         </StackPanel>
     </DataTemplate>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Add it to App.xaml,

```xml
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" />
            <!--  Other merged dictionaries here  -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="DataTemplates.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <!--  Other app resources here  -->
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Then you should be able to use it.

```xml
<ListView
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SomeViewTemplate}"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind Items, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Comment: I want to add items to GridView in this way:

`<GridView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SomeViewTemplate}" >
 <GridView.Items>
  <local:SomeModel val2="5" val1="vvdfbdb" />
  <local:SomeModel val2="3" val1="sdgdfshbdsh" />
 </GridView.Items>
</GridView>`

Everything worked fine before, but now all elements (val1, val2) are empty: Text = "", MaxRating by default 5.

Comment: By the way, in c#, this xaml code works as it should. Perhaps the problem is in the implementation of the SomeModel class in c++. But then why did everything work when the template was specified at the beginning of the page (template as in the question).

Comment: I cannot reproduce. You can refer to [XAML controls; bind to a C++/WinRT property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/binding-property) and [XAML items controls; bind to a C++/WinRT collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/binding-collection) for c++.

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT “I cannot reproduce” - You cannot reproduce behavior that I described? That is, did you manage to create a DataGrid, as in my comment above, using a DataTemplate that can be used in all pages (files) in c++? If you mean this, it would be sooooooo grateful if you share the complete application code in which this simple functionality is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

When I placed [DataTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.datatemplate?view=windows-app-sdk-1.3#remarks) in `App.xaml` or a separate ResourceDictionary as @AndrewKeepCoding answered, a Xaml Compiler error at `x:DataType`, *XamlCompiler error WMC0612: The XAML Binary Format (XBF) generator reported syntax error '0x09C4' : Property Not Found*, was raised. However, It's necessary to specify `x:DataType` in order to make the `DataTemplate` take effect.

So, my conclusion is `DataTemplate` cannot be global in c++ and [DataTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.datatemplate?view=windows-app-sdk-1.3#remarks) also states limited properties to use.

[Binding to a C++/WinRT collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/binding-collection) costs me a long time until I find [PhotoEditor](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK-Samples/tree/101bbd12b6b6cd681ad841174fb36f4c3f430e7e/Samples/PhotoEditor/cpp-winui/PhotoEditor) sample. Must specify [IInspectable](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK-Samples/blob/101bbd12b6b6cd681ad841174fb36f4c3f430e7e/Samples/PhotoEditor/cpp-winui/PhotoEditor/Project.idl#L43) instead of a custom runtime class name.

[image]

```
import "BookSku.idl";

namespace App1
{
    [default_interface]
    runtimeclass MainWindow : Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Window
    {
        MainWindow();
        Int32 MyProperty;
        Windows.Foundation.Collections.IVector<IInspectable> BookSkus{ get; };
    }
}
```

[image]

**Update**:

According to [Resource dictionaries with {x:Bind}](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth#resource-dictionaries-with-xbind), It's possible to use x:Bind and x:DataType in Resource dictionaries. That's why it works in c#. But there is no document about how to implement it in cppwinrt. A related thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/98422/15511041

Comment: @breadman I have updated my answer about [why it works in c#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth#resource-dictionaries-with-xbind).